# Min/max with Option[T] for possibly empty Seq?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm doing a bit of Scala gymnastics where I have `Seq[T]` in which I try to find the "smallest" element. This is what I do right now:

```
val leastOrNone = seq.reduceOption { (best, current) =>
    if (current.something < best.something) current
    else best
}
```

It works fine, but I'm not quite satisfied - it's a bit long for such a simple thing, and [I don't care much for "if"s](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/). Using `minBy` would be much more elegant:

```
val least = seq.minBy(_.something)
```

... but `min` and `minBy` throw exceptions when the sequence is empty. Is there an idiomatic, more elegant way of finding the smallest element of a possibly empty list as an `Option`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, [`minByOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#minByOption[B](f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering[B]):Option[A])/`maxByOption` is now part of the standard library and returns `None` if the sequence is empty:

```
seq.minByOption(_.something)
```

```scala
List((3, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (5, 'c')).minByOption(_._1) // Option[(Int, Char)] = Some((1,b))
List[(Int, Char)]().minByOption(_._1)                // Option[(Int, Char)] = None
```

Answer (score 79):

```
seq.reduceOption(_ min _)
```

does what you want?

---

Edit: Here's an example incorporating your `_.something`:

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
val seq = Seq(Foo(1,1),Foo(2,0),Foo(0,3))
val ord = Ordering.by((_: Foo).b)
seq.reduceOption(ord.min)  //Option[Foo] = Some(Foo(2,0))
```

or, as generic method:

```
def minOptionBy[A, B: Ordering](seq: Seq[A])(f: A => B) = 
  seq reduceOption Ordering.by(f).min
```

which you could invoke with `minOptionBy(seq)(_.something)`

Comment: it is also possible to use `seq reduceOption math.min`. This is more efficient because it doesn't require an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Antoras good thought, but I believe any differences are in practice optimized away - at least, that's what my microbenchmark shows

Answer (score 9):

A safe, compact and `O(n)` version with Scalaz:

```
xs.nonEmpty option xs.minBy(_.foo)
```

Answer (score 6):

Hardly an option for any larger list due to `O(nlogn)` complexity:

```
seq.sortBy(_.something).headOption
```

Comment: Breaks Occam's razor. Its fragments are sharp and dangerous!
The question was to find the maximum safely, not to sort the list.

Comment: @fatuhoku from a mathematical (and therefore pure FP?) point of view, `sortBy` + `headOption` seems like equivalent to `minByOpt` — why does it break Occam's razor?

Comment: @EricAllik Hmmm. No idea why I wrote that. I clearly didn't know what Occam's razor actually was a couple of years ago. Shameful!

Now I have more of an appreciation for answers like this, despite the accepted answer being a better idea.

Answer (score 5):

Also, it is available to do like that

```
Some(seq).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.minBy(_.something))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import util.control.Exception._
allCatch opt seq.minBy(_.something)
```

Or, more verbose, if you don't want to swallow other exceptions:

```
catching(classOf[UnsupportedOperationException]) opt seq.minBy(_.something)
```

Alternatively, you can pimp all collections with something like this:

```
import collection._

class TraversableOnceExt[CC, A](coll: CC, asTraversable: CC => TraversableOnce[A]) {

  def minOption(implicit cmp: Ordering[A]): Option[A] = {
    val trav = asTraversable(coll)
    if (trav.isEmpty) None
    else Some(trav.min)
  }

  def minOptionBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): Option[A] = {
    val trav = asTraversable(coll)
    if (trav.isEmpty) None
    else Some(trav.minBy(f))
  }
}

implicit def extendTraversable[A, C[A] <: TraversableOnce[A]](coll: C[A]): TraversableOnceExt[C[A], A] =
  new TraversableOnceExt[C[A], A](coll, identity)

implicit def extendStringTraversable(string: String): TraversableOnceExt[String, Char] =
  new TraversableOnceExt[String, Char](string, implicitly)

implicit def extendArrayTraversable[A](array: Array[A]): TraversableOnceExt[Array[A], A] =
  new TraversableOnceExt[Array[A], A](array, implicitly)
```

And then just write `seq.minOptionBy(_.something)`.

Comment: -1 for the equivalent of an empty catch block. Any other exception thrown will be swallowed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem before, so I  extends Ordered  and implement the compare function.
here is example:

```
 case class Point(longitude0: String, latitude0: String)  extends Ordered [Point]{

  def this(point: Point) = this(point.original_longitude,point.original_latitude)
  val original_longitude = longitude0
  val original_latitude = latitude0

  val longitude = parseDouble(longitude0).get 
  val latitude = parseDouble(latitude0).get  

  override def toString: String = "longitude: " +original_longitude +", latitude: "+ original_latitude

  def parseDouble(s: String):  Option[Double] = try { Some(s.toDouble) } catch { case _ => None }

  def distance(other: Point): Double =
    sqrt(pow(longitude - other.longitude, 2) + pow(latitude - other.latitude, 2))

 override def compare(that: Point): Int = {
  if (longitude < that.longitude)
    return -1
  else if (longitude == that.longitude && latitude < that.latitude)
    return -1
  else
    return 1
 }
}
```

so if I have a seq of Point
I can ask for max or min method

```
  var points =  Seq[Point]()

val maxPoint = points.max
val minPoint = points.min
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem that min and max on an empty collection throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like:

```
case class Foo(num: Int)

val foos: Seq[Foo] = Seq(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))
val noFoos: Seq[Foo] = Seq.empty

def minByOpt(foos: Seq[Foo]): Option[Foo] =
  foos.foldLeft(None: Option[Foo]) { (acc, elem) => 
    Option((elem +: acc.toSeq).minBy(_.num)) 
  }
```

Then use like:

```
scala> minByOpt(foos)
res0: Option[Foo] = Some(Foo(1))

scala> minByOpt(noFoos)
res1: Option[Foo] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

For scala < 2.13

```
Try(seq.minBy(_.something)).toOption
```

For scala 2.13

```
seq.minByOption(_.something)
```

Answer (score -5):

In Haskell you'd wrap the [`minimumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v%3aminimumBy) call as

```
least f x | Seq.null x = Nothing
          | otherwise  = Just (Seq.minimumBy f x)
```

Comment: I'd avoid the exception in the first place -- use the guard to rule out the chance of the exception occuring. That's semantically neater than leaning on the exception semantics to give you an optional value.

Comment: Haskell is cool, no doubt. But "this is how you can do it in another programming language" doesn't answer the question.