# more elegant way to write if( list.nonEmpty) Some(list.max) else None?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, max, scala-option

`List.max` returns the "largest" element of a list based on some ordering... But if the list is empty you'll get a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max` exception. I don't really like littering code with if statements or matches or whatever. I want something like `headOption` for `max`, but I'm not seeing such a method. What's the most elegant way to get the equivalent of `list.maxOption`?

Comment: wouldn't that just move that if-clause somewhere else?

Comment: put the implementation inside a type class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert a Try into an Option:

```
Try(empty.max).toOption
```

You can also use reduceOption (as given in [scala - Min/max with Option[T] for possibly empty Seq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922237/scala-min-max-with-optiont-for-possibly-empty-seq)):

```
l.reduceOption(_ max _)
```

Comment: Although this option is very elegant, in terms of performance, an `if` is vastly cheaper than opening a `try` block and possibly generating an exception with stack trace. If you case about perf, pick one of the other options.

Comment: I like all these answers, but choosing this one for the link to even more ideas.

Answer (score 13):

Or write your own:

```
implicit class WithMaxOption[T: Ordering](self: Seq[T]) {
  def maxOption() = if(self.isEmpty) None else Some(self.max)
}

List(1,2,3).maxOption  // Some(3)
List[Int]().maxOption  // None
```

Comment: For my own education: Is there a reason to use `Seq[T]` here rather than `Traversable[T]`?

Comment: @Rob, No reason. More general is fine.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, pre-2.13.

Answer (score 9):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, [`minOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#minOption%5BB%3E:A%5D(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering%5BB%5D):Option%5BA%5D)/[`maxOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#maxOption%5BB%3E:A%5D(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering%5BB%5D):Option%5BA%5D) are now part of the standard library:

```
List(34, 11, 98, 56, 43).maxOption // Option[Int] = Some(98)
List[Int]().maxOption              // Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way to accomplish it:

```
Some(list).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.max)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another formulation would be

```
list.headOption.map(_ => list.max)
```

Comment: I tend to agree!The thing to remember is that the function in a map/filter method doesn't have to use the argument that is passed to it